# Is Perl a standard for *nix hosting companies?

Tags: perl, standard, hosting-services

I never worked with Perl but in this community I bump time and again on recommendations to work with it, often as a "completion" for shell scripts.

Is Perl a standard for *nix hosting companies?
For example, if my hosting provider provides me with SSH access but doesn't include Perl (rather, say, only PHP and Node.JS) should I leave this hosting provider?

Thanks,

Comment: BTW, what is a one-liner safe check to test if Perl is working properly? A nice appendix to an answer about the standard.

Comment: “if my hosting provider provides me with SSH access but doesn't include Perl (rather, say, only PHP and Node.JS) should I leave this hosting provider?” — surely the answer is that if you need Perl, you should look elsewhere, and otherwise it doesn’t matter?

Comment: @StephenKitt generally yes but I want to broaden my general knowledge about hosting companies, learning if this is a standard and if so why; I don't think I would have asked a similar question about Python or Java ...

Comment: What kind of hosting? Perl is a pretty basic part of the *nix world, but it is no longer very commonly used for cgi scripts. If your hosting company gives you a Linux machine, you can safely assume it has Perl. If it is another form of *nix, it will almost certainly have perl (I believe only AIX doesn't install perl by default). Since you mention node.JS, you're probably working with Windows hosts so that's a different issue altogether.

Comment: @terdon Node typically runs on Linux, not Windows, AFAIK...

Comment: @StephenKitt oh. I was under the impression that is is more common in the Windows world, but [it looks like I was wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js#Platform_architecture). Thanks.

Comment: @terdon indeed I work only with Linux servers ; my current hosting provider uses CentOS, Bash for operation.

Comment: Then it has Perl. All Linux flavors (all that I know of, at least, and certainly CentOS) install Perl by default.

Comment: Noting that "having perl" and "being able to use Perl for your dynamic website" are two different things, though, so if you want the latter then you may still be out of luck regardless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can run Perl on any hosting provider providing VPS or anything more serious. Perl is a difficult language in terms of syntax, so at least in some usecases, you might do better with something more appropriate for the web, i.e. PHP/Ruby/RoR. There's no such thing as "standard" for hosting companies. Some even provide Windows hosting and Windows by default doesn't contain Perl.